# How to disable testing of rswag files with rspec, but only use them for documentation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rswag

I have problem with rswag `spec/integration/*_spec.rb` files witch goes in the main thread when I run `rspec`. In my project I use rswag lib only for creating documentation but not testing.
Result: `rspec` - run all tests except rswag. And `rake rswag` run only `spec/integration/*` for documentation.

Comment: any solution yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest solution I could figure out was running tests under a specific folder. In my case I have integration tests under `spec/` folder and rswag tests under `spec/requests/`, so I can do it like this: `rspec --pattern spec/*_spec.rb`

In your case should be `rspec --pattern spec/integration/*_spec.rb`.

See more about the `--pattern` option [here](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-8/docs/command-line/pattern-option).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this gonna work.